# Can my MacBook Pro can have up to 8GB of memory?

Tags: memory, macbook-pro

I downloaded a memory scanner tool and it says I have 2x2GB memory installed. This is correct. But then it says I can install 2x4GB memory so that I can have 8GB of memory. I'm not sure if this is correct, how can I find out?

Model is MacBook Pro 5,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [specifications page](http://www.apple.com/uk/macbookpro/specs.html) **on Apples website**:

> - 2.0GHz or 2.2GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 processor with 6MB shared L3 cache; or optional 2.3GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 processor with 8MB shared L3 cache
> - 4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1333MHz DDR3 memory; **two SO-DIMM slots support up to 8GB**

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out, is to use the memory selection tool on [crucial.com](http://crucial.com)  Since you didn't post your exact Macbook Pro model, there is really no way for us to tell, otherwise.

Comment: That's what I used. The model is MacBookPro5,3.

Comment: My 13" 2009 MBP also rocks 8GB.